# Is there a zipped file log handler for Quarkus?

Tags: logging, quarkus

The Quarkus [guide to logging](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.file-file-logging) mentions file handlers and how to configure them, but it does not mention anything about zipping log-files. Log4j2 offers the possibility for a rolling file appender to automatically zip all old log files. Does Quarkus have the same functionality? If yes, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use a sys property  -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$path

and add something like this to your configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/myapp.log"
       filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/myapp-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

it will compress log file to gz file