# How to gzip Log Rotation File in Quarkus?

Tags: logging, quarkus

I am building an application using Quarkus and i am using logging. How could i use gzip compression on my log Rotation files?

I didn't get anything related this on https://quarkus.io/guides/logging.

Comment: This is not something supported currently, but feel free to open an issue asking for the feature

Comment: You can make a cronjob script which can do that for you. It’s not a default functionality that comes with file logging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69556918/175554 and watch https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12260